# creating google chart with json data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a line chart using json data. But I'm unable to create it using the given json data. The json data is as follows:

```
JSON
{
           "Billings":{
              "apr 15":100,
              "may 15":111,
              "jun 15":112
           },
           "Revenue":{
              "apr 15":200,
              "may 15":211,
              "jun 15":212
           },
           "Net profit":{
              "apr 15":150,
              "may 15":151,
              "jun 15":152
           },
           "Gross Margin %":{
              "apr 15":"56%",
              "may 15":"59%",
              "jun 15":"58%"
           }
}
```

What I've tried so far is this:

```
HTML
<div google-chart chart="chartObject" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>

JS

$scope.jsonData = {
           "Billings":{
              "apr 15":100,
              "may 15":111,
              "jun 15":112
           },
           "Revenue":{
              "apr 15":200,
              "may 15":211,
              "jun 15":212
           },
           "Net profit":{
              "apr15":150,
              "may 15":151,
              "jun 15":152
           },
           "Gross Margin %":{
              "apr 15":"56%",
              "may 15":"59%",
              "jun 15":"58%"
           }
        };

function processArray(json) {
          var chartData = [];
          for (var i = 0, l = json.length; i < l; i++) {
            console.log(json[i].Billings['apr 15']);
            chartData.push({ c: [ { v: json[i].Billings['apr 15']}]});
            console.log(chartData);
          }
          return chartData;
        }
var chartData = processArray($scope.jsonData);

$scope.chartObject = {
          "type": "LineChart",
          "displayed": false,
          "data": {
            "cols": [
              {
                "id": "year",
                "label": "Year",
                "type": "string",
                "p": {}
              },
              {
                "id": "billings-id",
                "label": "Billings",
                "type": "number",
                "p": {}
              }
            ],
            "rows": chartData
          },
          "options": {
            "title": "Sales per month",
            "isStacked": "true",
            "fill": 20,
            "displayExactValues": true,
            "vAxis": {
              "title": "Sales unit",
              "gridlines": {
                "count": 10
              }
            },
            "hAxis": {
              "title": "Year"
            }
          },
          "formatters": {}
        };
```

Basically I want to iterate through the json data and create a line chart. As you can see I have tried iterating but I get an empty array. I've tried other ways too but I'm not able to understand the JSON data it seems. Any help or a hint would help me get started as I'm stuck on this one.

**UPDATE:**
I tried this and it works but doesn't seem the best method and best practice for larger data.

```
Modified json
$scope.jsonData = [{
           "Billings":{
              "apr 15":100,
              "may 15":111,
              "jun 15":112
           },
           "Revenue":{
              "apr 15":200,
              "may 15":211,
              "jun 15":212
           },
           "Net profit":{
              "apr15":150,
              "may 15":151,
              "jun 15":152
           },
           "Gross Margin %":{
              "apr 15":"56%",
              "may 15":"59%",
              "jun 15":"58%"
           }
        }];

JS
function processArray(json) {
          var chartData = [];
          for (var i = 0, l = json.length; i < l; i++) {
            chartData.push({ c: [ {v: 'april 15'}, {v: json[i].Billings['apr 15']}, {v: json[i].Revenue['apr 15']}]}, { c: [ { v: 'may 15'}, {v: json[i].Billings['may 15']}, {v: json[i].Revenue['may 15']}]});
            console.log(chartData);
          }
          return chartData;
        }
var chartData = processArray($scope.jsonData);
```

This works but I'm calling each month and that's where it doesn't seems right. What if the data gets bigger? I need a better solution. Sorry for not giving the most important info is that I'm using angular directive http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/

Comment: you need to parse your data using -> JSON.parse(json);

Comment: another thing you are missing closing " } " in your JSON string.

Comment: edited that one but what will this do? I've tried it but getting error.

Comment: Try this,var chartData = JSON.parse(processArray($scope.jsonData)); as you need to prase your data.

Comment: are you able to change the format of the JSON data in the source, before it gets to the page? ideally, it would in the format needed by Google, then you could just create the DataTable without having to manipulate each row -- see [example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#constructor_1) under the DataTable constructor

Comment: I tried using the DataTable constructor but was getting error. Actually I'm using a directive and not able to understand how do I use the constructor with it.